# How to set the Image / Icon on a WPF Page

Tags: wpf

I need to know how to set the very top left icon / image on a WPF page. I know how to do it in a WPF Window the page looks to be different.

Thanks,

Darren

Comment: I got it. You need to create your own NavigationWindow in order to set all of those window properties.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any support for changing the host window's icon based on its current page in a navigation-style application.

One workaround might be to introduce a property of type Image into your pages (perhaps derive all your pages from a base page, or introduce an IHasIcon interface and implement that), then bind the host window's icon to that. Something along the lines of:

```
<Window ...
    Icon="{Binding Content.Icon,ElementName=frame1>
    <Frame x:Name="frame1" ... />
</Window>
```

I haven't tried this but I've done similar things with binding a TextBlock to the "title" of the current page in a navigation application.

Comment: I got it. You need to create your own Navigation Window in order to set all of those window properties. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to modify the icon of the host window by adding the following (VB) code to the Loaded event of the page (I didn't test placing the code in the constructor).

```
Dim hostWindow As NavigationWindow =
        DirectCast(
            DirectCast(Me.VisualParent, 
                System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter).
                TemplatedParent, 
        System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationWindow)

Dim iconUri As New Uri("MyIcon.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
hostWindow.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(iconUri)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to a WPF application deployed as an XBAP, if so the same rules apply as a normal website and you would just place a favicon.ico in the root of your IIS website.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: No I'm referring to the System.Windows.Controls.Page class. I need to change the Icon on the Title bar.